# Error filling an int array in a typedef struct

Tags: c, arrays, struct, int, typedef

I tried to initialize the code array in Huffman struct but when i compiled it showed:

`Error expected expression before '{' token.` 
 How I can fix it?

```
typedef struct {  
    char letter;  
    float p;  
    int code[10];  
    }Huffman ;  
    Huffman line[4];   

    line[1].code[10]= {1,0,0,0};  
    line[2].code[10]= {0,0,1,0,1};  
    line[3].code[10]= {1,0,0,0,0};
```

Comment: `line[1].code[10]` is UB. Compiler complained for this for sure (incompatible types when assigning)

Comment: `code` only has 8 elements.  Why are to attempting to assign to index 10?

Comment: Assignment cannot occur outside of a function

Answer (score 1):

**Error**: The Error is due to way of initialization.

Statement1: `line[1].code[1] = 10; //WORKS` 
Statement2: `line[2].code[10]= {0,0,1,0,1};  //Wrong`

The Statement2 says something similar to compiler: Go to Structure Array named as `line[2]` and select element array `code` go to its 10 element which is wrong as only memory is reserved for 8 integer values but since there is no bound checking in C so that its terribly OK and paste an {0,0,1,0,1} element there, which is not possible as you are pasting these values to that one  element.

#### Better Approach

```
   //Declaring variable SIZE thus prevent BOUND CHECKING.
     int size;        
     size = sizeof(line[1].code)/sizeof(line[0].code[0])); //COUNTING NO OF ELEMENTS
     for (loop = 0; loop<size; loop++)
         line[1].code[loop] = loop;            //INITIALING BY Values 0,1,2,3,4....
```

Comment: `sizeof(line[1].code)/sizeof(int)` <-- This will break if anyone ever changes the data type of `code`. Replace `sizeof(int)` with `sizeof(line[0].code[0])` and it will work no matter what type `code` is. Much more robust.

Comment: O! Yea exactly, You are right! Appreciate your help :)